# Uploading and searching large pdf files

Tags: tomcat, pdf, full-text-search, pdf-generation, liferay

I currently have 6 100mb+ PDF documents which have searchable text layer enabled.

However when the documents are uploaded the images are showing negative in the preview and the text isn't visible. But when you download the documents from the site they are fully searchable again.

Any idea how I can search the content of these PDF's on liferay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This forum post reply might help: http:[Is it possible to search content from the PDF Document?](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/14051278#_19_message_14064180) and also this [reply](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/14051278#_19_message_14113263).